# Resultados da pesquisa Resultados da Web ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to run a query using knex.raw();

```
SELECT msg."msgId",
       msg.from_me,
       msg.message,
       msg."dataEnvio",
       msg.id_atendimento,
       msg.caption,
       msg.type,
       msg.leitura,
       msg."errorOnSend",
       msg.resp,
       msg."senderName",
       msg.encaminhada,
       msg.self,
       msg.sent,
       msg.read
FROM tb_atendimento_bot as att
   INNER JOIN LATERAL ((SELECT m.id as msgId,
                               m.from_me,
                               m.message,
                               m.msg_date_envio as dataEnvio,
                               m.id_atendimento,
                               m.caption,
                               m.type,
                               m.leitura,
                               m."errorOnSend",
                               m."quotedMsgBody" as resp,
                               m.sender_name as senderName,
                               m."isForwarded" as encaminhada,
                               m.self,
                               m.sent,
                               m.read
                        from tb_mensagens as m
                        WHERE (m.id_atendimento = att.id)
                        ORDER BY m.id DESC limit 10)) msg
      ON true
WHERE att.id IN(${ids_atendimentos.map(() => '?')})
  AND att.status = true`,
[...ids_atendimentos])
```

but it outputs that the from clause is making a wrong reference, I have to use lateral join for this, any ideas on what`s wrong?

Comment: As a starter, remove the nested parentheses after the `LATERAL JOIN`.

Comment: i removed but it goes to Syntax error invalid reference in or near to SELECT, i've placed the parentheses to remove this error, but this other one happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this error comes from the postgres version, i updated and the query worked fine.